# Change background color FullCalender react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using FullCalender in react to show a calendar that displays events.
At the moment I am using a day grid and I was wondering how I could change the background colour of the grid.

[today's date background color is always yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmVgg.png)

[This is how it looks on other days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbHnA.png)

What I want to do is change the background color so that the current day grid has a white background like the rest of the days

```
    <div>
    <FullCalendar
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        initialView="timeGridDay"
        nowIndicator={true}
        selectable
        selectOverlap={() => {
          return false;
        }}
        eventResizableFromStart
        droppable
        allDayMaintainDuration
      />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option for this in the API but if you explore the rendered calendar with your browser's element inspector you can see that the colour is set using a simple CSS class - the current day has the class `fc-day-today` set on it.

Therefore if we just set a rule to override the fullCalendar one, we can change the background colour to whatever we want:

```
.fc-day-today {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/jOBXmqy

Comment: how should I implement the css changes into my component?

Comment: @Abdul9401 I don't know anything about react sorry. But it's just a CSS rule...don't you have a .css file you can put it in?

Comment: I don't but even If I do that, how will it override the react component

Comment: add a wrapper to the fullCalendar to change the css